# Data Dependency, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dependencies

I am faced with a problem for a project at work. I am tasked to create a database (which I have). My problem is the files I need to create a database for sometimes depend on each other.

For example I have file name called Lakers, now within Lakers I can see that it is using other files such as Kobe and Shaq. Now Kobe and Shaq depends on other files also like Fisher and WorldPeace and so forth. I'm using MySQL, PHP, and Javascript for this project and there are about 1.8 GB of files in total. My question is what is the best way to start?

How can I show in PHP that the files are depended on each other just like how I described it? Any sort of advice will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. If you are using a RDBMS like mysql, then why do you talk about file dependencies? or are those files registered inside that database? Then you should explain that and post the current table layout you have.

Comment: well that's not so hard, just state that every has parent element and children, so you can always get his parent and his children

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that others can help you. You should explain what you have already tried or sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In the database, you can have a Schema that looks like follows:

Assuming a file can be dependent on more than one files

File:
(id, file_name)

File_Parent_Lookup
(id, file_id, file_parent_id)

So, now you can just query SQL when you want to find the file dependency.

As for the representation part, you should look for some tree drawing library in JavaScript, and then use it to depict the relations. You may need to transform the query output so that it can be processes by the library. I recommend you start with the library you find the simplest in Google("javascript graph visualization").